# How to open multiple tabs in IE8 from the command prompt?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, command-line-arguments, browser-tabs

What command line options can I use for opening multiple tabs in IE 8 from the command prompt or a .bat file? I've tried the URLs separated by `""`, commas, `<>` and `|`, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK IE doesn't support multiple URLs as command-line parameters. You can invoke it multiple times with a single URL each from a batch file or something, but that seems to open separate windows. For launching multiple URLs in tabs in a single IE window, use the following script:

```
var navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000;
var objIE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
objIE.Navigate2("http://www.site1.com");
objIE.Navigate2("http://www.site2.com", navOpenInBackgroundTab);
objIE.Navigate2("http://www.site3.com", navOpenInBackgroundTab);
objIE.Visible = true;
```

Save as StartIE.js, then either double-click in Windows Explorer, or use `wscript.exe StartIE.js` at the command prompt to launch.

Comment: You're welcome! Since you're new here, don't forget to accept whichever answer (if there are multiple) best solves your issue.

Comment: Cheers - works for me