# How to open multiple tabs in IE8 from batch file?

Tags: batch-file, internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

Upon searching for an answer to this question, I stumbled upon an almost [identical question](https://superuser.com/questions/513979/how-to-open-multiple-tabs-in-ie8-from-the-command-prompt) on this site, to which someone answered:

"For launching multiple URLs in tabs in a single IE window, use the following script:

```
var navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000;  
var objIE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");  
objIE.Navigate2("site1");  
objIE.Navigate2("site2", navOpenInBackgroundTab);  
objIE.Navigate2("site3", navOpenInBackgroundTab);  
objIE.Visible = true;
```

Save as StartIE.js, then either double-click in Windows Explorer, or use wscript.exe StartIE.js at the command prompt to launch."

When I run StartIE.js, I get and error from "Windows Script Host" that says:

```
Script: [file address]  
Line: 4  
Char: 1  
Error: Unspecified error  
Code: 80004005  
Source: (null)
```

Would anyone kindly point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (save as a .vbs file):

```
Const navOpenInBackgroundTab = &H1000

site1 = "site1.com"
site2 = "site2.com"
site3 = "site3.com"

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate2 site1
oIE.Navigate2 site2,navOpenInBackgroundTab
oIE.Navigate2 site3,navOpenInBackgroundTab

Set oIE = Nothing
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot for the help. Now I'm curios to understand why this worked, but I may need to learn the basis of programming first, which is after I identify which language this is written in.

Comment: It is vbscript (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) and uses the InternetExplorer.Application object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Navigate2 is a method from that object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The script assigns variables for each site, then it calls the method and uses one of the variables as an argument. The second argument for the last 2 calls is optional, which specifies to open it as a background tab, from browsernavconstants (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that was actually very helpful, with the limited understanding of basic programming that I have.